# Using the same OAuth token for multiple Twitter requests

Tags: twitter, oauth

I am working on an app that uses the same OAuth token and OAuth token secret for multiple requests to post a tweet on behalf of a user. On the first request, the tweet is successfully posted. However on subsequent requests I get an HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Could this be caused by reusing the OAuth tokens? I am also tweeting the same message on each request.

Answer (score 0):

There are two components of a Twitter error response, the HTTP status code (in this case 403) and an error code that provides more detail on the cause of the failure. Which error code are you seeing in the JSON response? It's possible that the error is regarding duplicate tweets.

[Twitter REST API error codes](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses)